# Гамма функция на python

Tags: python

```
def fac(x,n):
    i=1
    s=1
    while i<=n:
        s=s*((i+1)/i)**x*i/(x+i)
        i=i+1
    return s

print(fac(5,200000))#->119.99400022498341
```

Это код гамма функции. Работает вроде правильно, но сходимость медленная.

Comment: Вы забыли задать вопрос. Есть вот такая функция с медленной сходимостью, ну хорошо. Что вы хотите мы должны сами догадаться? )

Comment: Увеличить сходимость, если это можно.

Comment: Чисто питоном наверное вряд ли. С помощью `numba.njit` можно ускорить вычисления, тогда 100 млн. циклов считается за 1 секунду и даёт `119.99998821343507`. Тут явно нужна математика, чтобы поменять сами вычисления на какие-то другие. Изначально то задача перед вами какая стоит?

Comment: Посмотрите https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation, код на питоне, считает  мгновенно, gamma(6) - 120.00000000000021

Answer (score 3):

Просто ускорить код примерно в 40 раз можно с помощью `Numba` (ускорение и распараллеливание простых вычислений):

```py
from numba import njit

@njit
def fac(x,n):
    s=1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        s=s*((i+1)/i)**x*i/(x+i)
    return s

print(fac(5,100_000_000))
# 119.99998821343507
# 1 секунда
```

А дальше уже нужно в сторону математики смотреть - к чему эта формула сходится, кардинально тут улучшать в расчётах нечего чисто программными методами, потому что на каждом шаге меняется `i` и уменьшить вычисления между шагами алгоритма не получится. Кэширование тут тоже не поможет никак. Только математика.